# ReactJs Component Unexpected Token error on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to check if a prop is empty and add a condition to a react component.

Here is the code:

```
class Mycomp extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Mycomp">
                {this.props.title}
                if (this.props.title != '') {
                    console.log('Title is not empty');
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting an Unexpected Token error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Move your `if` condition before the `return` statement. (and use `!==` btw)

Comment: you can not have `if statement in your JSX`

Comment: `{ this.props.title || console.log("title is empty") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an `if` statement in your JSX like that. You are best to use turnery operators or do something like this:

```
return (
  <div className="Mycomp">
        {this.props.title ||''} 
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a if-else statement in return, use a ternary operator

```
class Mycomp extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.title != '') {
            console.log('Title is not empty');
        }
        return (
            <div className="Mycomp">
                {this.props.title}
                {this.props.title? 'Something here': 'Else something'}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use logical operator &&

```
class Mycomp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const title = this.props.title
    return (
      <div className="Mycomp">
         { title && title }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Or... `{ title }`